# Export complete Windows 10 installation to be installed in a virtual machine

Tags: windows-10, macos, virtual-machine, parallels, data-migration

I have an older computer that runs Windows 10 and has a bunch of apps installed and lots of documents on it. I want to "export" that installation and install it in a virtual machine on my Macbook **(Apple M1 CPU)**.

I could of course copy all data from the physical machine onto a external harddrive and from there copy everything over to the virtual machine, but it's a lot and can't be sure I don't miss any files.

I have created a system image via the "create system image" function of Windows 10, but it gave me a bunch of folders and three `.vhdx` files which don't help me in Parallels on my Mac (respectively I don't know how to use them).

So what would be a good approach to copy / clone my existing installation onto my Macbook (inside the VM) without installing the OS in the VM and copying everything over manually?

Comment: Can it be assumed your MacBook is using x86 silicon instead of an ARM/Apple silicon?

Comment: @Ramhound It is an ARM/Apple CPU. I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copying everything from the host machine onto a external hard drive and from there onto the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Using a third-party tool will give better results in this case.

I suggest the following tools :

- Install
  [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)
  on the old computer and backup the entire disk to USB
- Use AOMEI to
  [Create Windows PE or Linux Bootable Media](https://www.ubackup.com/help/create-bootable-disk.html)
  on another USB
- Create a new empty VM for Windows and set it to boot the above
  bootable media
- Boot the VM into the bootable media and restore the old Windows
  backup to the virtual disk of the VM.

---

If your Apple computer uses the M1 chip, you are out of luck.

The knowledge-base article
[About Parallels Desktop for Mac with Apple M1 chip](https://kb.parallels.com/125343) says:

> To run virtual machines on a Mac with Apple M1 chip, Parallels engineers created a new virtualization engine that uses the Apple M1 chip hardware-assisted virtualization and allows to run ARM-based virtual machines.

And also:

> To run Windows 11 and its applications on a Mac with Apple M1 Chip, you need to install Windows 11 on ARM that can run the majority of Intel-based Windows 11 applications by using a built-in emulator.

Comment: This all assumes the MacBook is Intel based instead of using Apple's own M1 silicon.

Comment: Right, I didn't think of this. I wonder if a VM can emulate Intel on the M1. The M1 should be fast enough to do that.

Comment: Windows on ARM can run x86/x64 software through software emulation.  Windows on ARM cannot be ran on x86/x64 hardware.  Windows 10 cannot be ran on ARM hardware.  Likewise, to my knowledge, macOS on M1 hardware can only perform x86/x64 software emulation.  However, Parallels is performing hardware virtualization not emulation, so I don't believe it can run x86/x64 operating systems.  Hardware virtualization is not emulation, hypervisors use the underlined hardware, there is no x86/x64 hardware on an M1 processor.

Comment: https://www.parallels.com/blogs/parallels-desktop-apple-silicon-mac/

Comment: All that article says it supports Windows on ARM which I already knew, and within Windows on ARM, can run x86/x64 which I also already knew.

Comment: Parallels can do this itself, to an Intel Mac. No prior backup required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention it's an M1 Macbook, so I think I'm out of options as, if I understand correctly, this won't work for me as only Windows 11 supports ARM hardware.

Comment: Yes, seems like it. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Parallels can import directly from a Windows PC, via network or external storage, to a Mac VM using Parallels Transporter Agent - but only on Intel. M1 is not yet supported [because it would require changing the actual windows version from X86 to ARM.]

See [Parallels KB - Transfer your PC to Mac using Parallels Desktop for Mac](https://kb.parallels.com/123929) for full instructions.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid this does not work for me - I forgot to mention it's an M1 Macbook

Comment: Then it cannot be done at all. You will need to start from a fresh install of Windows for ARM.

Comment: Very frustrating, but thank you anyways.